# UWP database designer for SQLite

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, database-design, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) tutorial and it seems you have to build all the relationships manually.
Is there any database visualizer/designer for visual studio which will help you to easily create an SQLite database? 
Something like this one: [image]

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: Currently there's no **official** support in UWP to create your database from a designer AND have both the SQL and C# code generated.*

If you're using EF Core with code first as done in the tutorial you're following, then there's **no designer** to help. After all it is 'code first' not designer first.

If you really want to design your database, you can use ErikEJ's Visual Studio Extension called [SQLite / SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox) . This will help you to design the database, but then you won't have a way to generate the C# DBContext and Entity classes for UWP, as UWP only supports EF Core (not EF 6).

So you'll either have to write the models yourself after designing the database and you're back at step 1 (so what's the use of using a visual designer), or write SQL queries yourself using [SQLite.NET-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) or any other SQLite NuGet package.

Comment: Not true: EF Core has tooling to create DbContext and classes from an existing database (scaffold-dbcontext)

Comment: I was thinking to work on model-first approach, but working with SQLite.